# Mysql view in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I created 2 mysql views, and has generated from them 2 model.

**MostPopularCoupon**

```
class MostPopularCoupon extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'most_popular_coupon';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('coupon_id', 'required'),
            array('coupon_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('left_coupons', 'length', 'max'=>22),
            array('stopped_at', 'safe'),
            array('left_coupons, coupon_id, stopped_at', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'left_coupons' => 'Left Coupons',
            'coupon_id' => 'Coupon',
            'stopped_at' => 'Stopped At',
        );
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('left_coupons',$this->left_coupons,true);
        $criteria->compare('coupon_id',$this->coupon_id);
        $criteria->compare('stopped_at',$this->stopped_at,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

**MostActiveCity**

```
class MostActiveCity extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'most_active_city';
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('mines', 'length', 'max'=>21),
            array('city', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('mines, city', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'mines' => 'Mines',
            'city' => 'City',
        );
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('mines',$this->mines,true);
        $criteria->compare('city',$this->city,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

But due to no experience, don't know how to use them correctly. I need to substitute company_id in the query to get the data of the company belongs to the current user...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. You're trying to get more data from a table called "company" based on the attribute company_id?

Comment: @ifsession 
yes. it is

Comment: I need different data for company_id where company_id = Yii::app()->user->company_id

Answer (score 0):

Please relock at your design. You would be better off having model classes of City{} and Coupon{}, then have functions for example MostPopularCoupons inside the Coupon class. You could then call them as functions of the class. For example.

In your model

```
class Coupon extends CActiveRecord
{

    // NOTE: This is important for your alias column.
    public $couponCount;

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'coupon';
    }
    ...
    public function MostPopularCoupons()
    {
       $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
       $Criteria->select = ' count(*) as couponCount ';
       $lstCoupons       = Coupon::model()->findAll($Criteria);

       return $lstCoupons;
    }

}
```

Then, in your controller

```
$coupon_id = 10;
$model1 = Coupon::model()->findByPK((int)$coupon_id);

$lstCouponCount = Coupon::MostPopularCoupons();
```